# Where() for a list of values

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to write the below as a linq statement without the foreach by someway pasing `emailList` into the linq query?

```
List<EmailFilter> el = new List<EmailFilter>();

foreach(string email in emailList) // emailList is string list of available emails
{
    el.AddRange( db.EmailFilters.Where(x => x.Email == email) ).ToList();
}
```

So I would populate `el` with a single linq query.

Comment: If this is all in/from the database you would be best off to do a join to get the results instead of getting it into memory and then filtering.

Comment: The string list of emails is not in the database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want to take every `EmailFilter` which `Email` is contained in the `emailList`. In this case LINQ can also help to improve readability:

```
List<EmailFilter> el = db.EmailFilters.Where(x => emailList.Contains(x.Email)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try :

```
List<EmailFilter> el  = db.EmailFilters.Where(x => emailList.Contains(x.Email) ).ToList();
```

Comment: No he isn't, Tim was faster by 3 seconds.

Comment: I wasn't making it up, thats what it said for me.

Comment: Yeah your right, timestamp confirms it, must have been an offset due to the ajax

Comment: Luckily you can assign rep to whomever you want, I'm sure Tim has enough to last a lifetime ;-)

Comment: Problem that both answers doesn't provide any explanation why `Contains` is a correct approach

Comment: @Fabio: I thought it was clear. He wants to take every email-filter which email is contained in the email-list. In this case LINQ can help to improve readability so that a comment is not really needed. **Edited** my answer

Comment: @TimSchmelter, my comment was more about the different between `Where` and `Where ... Contains` from EntityFramework point of view.

Comment: @Fabio: should be one query instead of multiple

Answer (score 0):

you can also write this as a join

```
var el = from emailFilter in db.EmailFilters
    join email in emailList on emailFilter.Email equals email
    select emailFilter;
```

Answer (score 0):

If el is a list, you can use AsEnumerable to join it with database table in linq.

```
var result= from p in db.EmailFilters
            join s in el.AsEnumerable() on p.Email=el.Email
             select p;
```